# MongoDB Typescript models: Convert from snake_case to camelCase

Tags: typescript, mongodb

so I have a mongo database that has all fields in `snake_case`

In typescript it would be nice if I could use classes as models, but then variables would need to be also in `snake_case`.. Can this be somehow changed so variables in typescript classes can be in `camelCase` format while database naming scheme stays the same?

Edit: I forgot to add, application is running in Node, and right now I'm just using standard mongodb library. I'm open to using something else if it solves this problem.

I hope I missed a trivial solution to this, any help is appreciated.

Thanks!